# Does "it argues ill" mean the same as “augurs ill”?

Tags: meaning, figurative-language, literature

Does "commend" mean "praise"? Does "it argues ill" mean the same as "augurs ill" or not?

> *Dr. (afterwards Professor) Balfour Stewart, in a
> communication to Nature, **commended** the boldness and honesty which
> had led Mr. Crookes to take this step. Crookes himself took the view
> that it was the duty of scientists to make such investigation. He writes:
> "**It argues ill** for the boasted freedom of opinion among scientific men
> that they have so long refused to institute a scientific investigation into the existence and nature of facts asserted by so many competent and
> credible witnesses, and which they are freely invited to examine when
> and where they please.*

*[The History of Spiritualism](https://books.google.it/books?id=_1w1DwAAQBAJ&pg=PT655&dq=%22it%20argues%20ill%22%20%22boasted%20freedom%20of%20opinion%20among%20scientific%20men%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi66OPbxZrqAhUHyaYKHe7EDSMQ6AEwAnoECAYQAg#v=onepage&q=%22it%20argues%20ill%22%20%22boasted%20freedom%20of%20opinion%20among%20scientific%20men%22&f=false)*   By A.C Doyle
<sub>XI.THE RESEARCHES OF SIR WILLIAM CROOKES (1870-1874)</sub>

From *[Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/something-bodes-ill-augurs-ill)*

> ### sth bodes ill/augurs ill
>
> If something bodes ill or augurs ill, it gives you a reason to fear that something harmful might happen soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, "commend" means praise.

"Argues ill" is probably a typo or someone mistaking the idiom. They should have said "augurs ill" as you suggest. (Or perhaps some other phrase that isn't coming to mind.)

Regarding the second one, it's fairly common for people to substitute a familiar word for an unfamiliar word that sounds similar. Like I often see people write "a mute point" when they mean "a moot point", etc etc.

Comment: See the comments on the answer below. Your point about "commend" is commendable. Your point about "augers" is not. It ignores the thrust of the passage and what can be discovered in minutes about the author. Fellows of the Royal Society are not noted for sloppy writing, nor are professional editors.

Comment: I did a Google search for "argues ill" and of all the hits found, only one actually used it as a phrase like that. The rest were like, "... he argues, ill will result" or "he argues, 'Ill prepares us for ..." etc. Is it possible that the writer intended the sentence as written? Possibly. But it's a decidedly odd constructions. "It argues ill"? Like, someone makes an argument that is ill? Even if we understand it to mean "this is an argument that leads to an ill conclusion", then the "thrust of the passage" is the same as "augurs ill", so an argument from context doesn't really help.

Comment: BTW "augurs" means "predicts". An "auger" is a wood boring tool.

Comment: https://www.google.it/search?hl=en&biw=1320&bih=647&tbm=bks&sxsrf=ALeKk011VvTa_mCivUc1U75v1gHT8glAug%3A1593005639263&ei=R1bzXtHOD5TbmwW565uQCA&q=%22it+argues+ill%22+%22opinion+among+scientific+men%22&oq=%22it+argues+ill%22+%22opinion+among+scientific+men%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...152783.156266.0.157199.19.19.0.0.0.0.147.1989.2j14.16.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..3.2.273...33i10k1.0.tDcs9yF5cJo Plenty instances of "argues ill"...

Answer (score 4):

I agree that "commend" means "praise" here.
 I disagree that "**argues ill**" has anything to do with "augurs ill". The latter phrase means "to predict something bad". The meaning here is plain without assuming a typographical error. Paraphrasing to simplify the structure,

"It **argues** ill for ... freedom of opinion among scientists ... that they have refused to investigate" (spiritualist claptrap).

This means that saying (**arguing**) that scientists are open-minded is not justified, based on the cited evidence of their close-mindedness.

Comment: I suppose you *might* be right here, given that ***to argue ill** [for something]* [did actually have some currency](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=augurs+ill+for%2Cargues+ill+for&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Caugurs%20ill%20for%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cargues%20ill%20for%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Caugurs%20ill%20for%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cargues%20ill%20for%3B%2Cc0) a century or two ago. But it was never that common, and I'd say that today only ***augurs ill*** still "exists" - and that's effectively as a "frozen / affected form" anyway.

Comment: @FFRM A century or two ago is just right for this text, "Spiritualism and its recent converts", ca. 1871.

Comment: I think it is absolutely clear that Crookes wrote "argues ill of" in the sense of "speaks ill of." According to Wikipedia, he was the son of a wealthy tailor from the north of England. It would probably take much research to find what flavor of English was natural to him, but it was most probably not Oxbridge English. The thrust of the quotation is not one of prediction but of criticism. The oddities of English from the north of England make the spoken form of it sometimes incomprehensible to me (as I suppose mine is to those from York). Received English is likely irrelevant, context is not.